# Orfeo Toolbox is installed but not visible in Processing Toolbox

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

maybe someone had the same problem and solved it already:
I did an "Advanced Install" setup of OSGeo4W enabling otb-bin, then started QGIS 2.18.15 and entered the following correct paths (my computer has Windows 7, 32bit) under Processing -> Options -> Providers:

OTB applications folder: C:\OSGeo4W\apps\orfeotoolbox\applications

OTB command line tools folder: C:\OSGeo4W\bin

The "Activate" button was of course enabled too, I confirmed and restarted QGIS (a couple of times): nothing happens, no Orfeo Toolbox visible in the processing toolbox...
Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?